# Crash on android 4.4.2: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-theme

My application is crashing with this error when i run it into android 4.4.2:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.
```

I'm using a Toolbar and i'm setting the base theme as .NoActionBar so it should work fine.

This is my default theme.xml:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
</style>
```

I've tried also `windowActionBar = false` and `windowNoTitle = true` but is still not working.
Can someone help me with this error?

**EDIT**
In the manifest i'm just doing this:

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Mezzo"
```

with

```
 <style name="AppTheme.Mezzo" parent="AppTheme.Base">
 ...
 </style>
```

Comment: are you sure your activity is not using a different theme declared in your manifest?

Comment: No, in the manifest i'm just setting the theme of the Application a child of the AppTheme.Base.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this style

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

And using it in manifest

```
 android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
```

In your activity tag

Comment: Just tried and still not working... don't know what to do now, really what other information do you guys need?